# passing nsdata using custom url scheme

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, xcode, iphone-sdk-3.0

i just want to know can we pass nsdata or array datatype from one app to other app using custom scheme? if not then how much can be the maximum length of custom url variable that i can pass.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can pass 255 bytes in URL. There is no other method

Comment: and can we pass nsdata or any object like this